# ReactJS - sending an empty object with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I'm using saga.js and when I make my request, my file is empty.

I need to do something extra to send an object through saga yield?

**My saga.js:**

```
export function* uploadS3Request({ payload }) {
  console.log('payload', payload)
  const { uploadTypeName, title, imageHeight, imageWidth, file } = payload

  try {
    yield call(api.post, `https://someurl.com/s3`, {
      uploadTypeName,
      title,
      imageHeight,
      imageWidth,
      file
    })

    toast.success('SUCCESS TEST');

  } catch (err) {
    toast.error('Error while trying to update image');
  }
}
```

**This is the console.log from payload in my saga.js: (all the informations are here)**
[image]

**But my request, file is empty:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not redux or redux-saga issue, but problem of making multipart form body.

By assuming you are using `axios` or `apisauce`, you will want to append the file to form data and send.

```
...
const { uploadTypeName, title, imageHeight, imageWidth, file } = payload
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('uploadTypeName', uploadTypeName);
...

yield call(api.post, `https://someurl.com/s3`, formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
...
```